# Is it grammatically correct to say "John, good morning to you"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Two hosts on the Today Show constantly say "John, good morning to you" when starting to speak with someone on air. The others usually stick with "John, good morning".  Adding the "to you" seems to double up on who they already directed the good morning to at the beginning.  It just sounds very weird.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding _to you_ simply adds emphasis. It's like saying _Happy Birthday to you_.

Comment: Yes, emphasis that can also add a personal touch, since you are singling out that it is *to you* (and not someone else) that I am saying *good morning* to. In other words it is comparable to *happy birthday to you.* Of course, we usually just say *Happy birthday* unless singing the song.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly grammatical, and I can't work out what about it you thought might not be grammatical.

*To you* is arguably redundant, but redundancy *per se* has no effect on grammaticality. *Good morning to you* is quite common, usually with an emphasis (eg as an answer to *Good morning*).

In the context of a broadcast show, the interviewer's greeting often needs to serve additional functions above the normal function of a greeting: it must indicate to the audience that an interview is starting, and it may also need to identify the interviewee to the audience.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is *grammatical*.  Maybe adding "to you" could be see as being slightly wordier than necessary, but it's very much a judgment call.  Until you raised the question I've never heard this particular usage and thought it unusual or questionable.